# How to access context given in query from inside plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, plugins, jquery-plugins

It's possible to do the following:

```
$(selector, context)
```

But how does `$.fn.pluginX` find out what what the given context was? For example:

```
$(selector, context).pluginX()
```

---

I've a case where a third party plugin assumes the window / document is the current one.

---

### Edit:

I made the assumption that a document is meant by "context", but it's not always a document I guess. In my case, I'm doing cross-document stuff like `$(sel, iframe.contentDocument).pluginX()` and I want to make sure that if the plugin does `$('body').append`, then it should do `$('body', theSameDocumentContext).append`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Don't check the context, check the `.prevObject`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon could you explain further?

Comment: See my answer. Hope it help.

Comment: Why do you need the context? there's probably a far better way of doing this that doesn't require retrieving the context in that way.

Comment: @AdamLynch Do the cross-documents have their own version of jQuery attached? If they did, the solution could be as simple as getting a reference to that jQuery instance object instead of the root one. Working cross-document with jQuery can be difficult, for example, event bubbling won't always work as expected.

Comment: @KevinB nope, ideally only the one calling the function does. I understand that `iframe.contentWindow.$(...).pluginX()` would work. About the event bubbling, do you anything you can link me to on that?

Comment: The weirdness stems from the fact that events triggered on elements in another document won't bubble up to the same document that jQuery was bound to, so delegated events may not work normally, which may or may not affect things depending on what the plugin uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery element has a `.context` attribute. You can use it inside your plugin :

```
$.fn.pluginX = function(){
    console.log(this.context);
}
```

But this is not reliable, there is too much variant. The value of context will always be `document` except if you pass an `HTMLElement` (like that):

```
$('p', document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]);
```

But you can pass different context :

```
//All working :
$('p', document.getElementsByTagName('div'));
$('p', document.querySelector('div'));
$('p', document.querySelectorAll('div'));
$('p', document.getElementByID('id'));
$('p', 'div');
$('p', $('div'));
$('p', $('div').add('p'));
///... ran out of ideas
```

Now, it is important to know that passing a context is [exactly the same has doing `.find()`](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L200) :

```
$('p', 'div') === $('div').find('p');
```

Also, jQuery always store the previous jQuery object when chaining. If it is the initial call (no traversal method used), the previous object will be the document.

Knowing that information, if you want to get the *"real"* context, you can get that last element. jQuery have the property `.prevObject`. Use it :

```
$.fn.pluginX = function(){
    console.log(this.prevObject);
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, `this.prevObject.get(0).ownerDocument` will do the job (or `this.prevObject.get(0)` if it's already a document.

Answer (score 0):

$(selector, context) is same as $('context selector') and you can get it through this.selector, however this could be tricky for chained selectors.

for example:

```
$('.articles', '.section').pluginX()
//within the pluginX  plugin function definition you can call this.selector

$.fn.pluginX = function(){
    ...
    //this.selector = '.section .articles';
    //this.selector.split(' ')[0] = '.section' //scope
    ...
}
```

But the above calculation will fail, if we have

```
$('.articles .writer', '.section').pluginX();
```

or

```
$('.writer', '.section .articles').pluginX();
```

If you have some presumption about either selector or context then it may help you to draft a logic. Let me know that helps you, or you could elaborate your specific requirement and we can try find a solution.